# Java SSLSocket - how to set local port

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

How can i set the local port when creating a SSLSocket?

This is how i create the socket:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();  
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
```

It seems that createSocket method doesnt have a parameter for setting LOCAL_PORT and the constructor of SSLSocket doesnt work either.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider reading the Javadoc?

Comment: hmm, actually i did and read it too. If you read it too, you will see that SSLSocket doesn't implement a method which allows you to set the local port.

Comment: I've read it many times, thanks, and there most certainly is a method, although nobody said it was in SSLSocket. See @Philipp's answer. NB You haven't needed to add that provider for about ten years.

Comment: ok thx for the provider tip. i removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variant of the createSocket method which is inherited by SSLSocketFactory from SocketFactory which takes a host and a port. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: well i need a SSLSocket not a normal Socket. because the server requires that.

Comment: You will get an SSLSocket. SSLSocketFactory extends SocketFactory, and SSLSocket extends Socket. When you call the createSocket method of SSLSocketFactory, it will return an SSLSocket, even when it inherited the method declaration of this particular variant from SocketFactory. It does, however, return it "disguised" as a normal Socket reference. But you should be able to downcast the returned Socket to an SSLSocket.

Comment: @HasanTahsin, which method have you tried that doesn't work? Calling  `createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort)` on your `SSLSocketFactory` is the way to go. Why would that be a nasty way to do it?

Comment: @Bruno i'm sorry. I had misunderstood the answer. It Works